# Differential Gear Alternative Ratio

Tags: mercedes-benz, differential

I have Mercedes-Benz E-200 Estate Model 1995 with a Differential Ratio Number 3.92; Which I couldn't found; So I'm looking for a Differential Gear EQUIVALENT to 3.92 Ratio? For example can I use 3.90 Ratio, My car have chassis Number WDB 1240791F322094 Differential Number 1623247 3.92

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is check out the assembly with your Mercedes dealer. They may be able to tell you what vehicles your differential assembly was fitted to. If you are not intending to buy new, then a list of vehicles it was fitted to will enable you to carry out a broader search for vehicles from vehicle dismantlers.

Answer (score -1):

Not an answer but bear in mind if you change ratio your speedometer will be inaccurate.
Affordable after market easily fitted devices are available for both old school needle
and dial and digital speedometers